# How can I convert this jQuery handler on pure Javascript cross-browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jQuery handler :

```
$('a[rel="entra_handler"]').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).children().fadeOut(200);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).children().fadeIn(200);
    }
);
```

and I'd like to convert it to pure Javascript, that works with every kind of browsers.
Is it easy and possible?

Comment: Well, I suppose you could use a JavaScript framework that's abstracted out the cross-browser issues.

Comment: @Charles you mean like... what's its name again... jQuery?

Comment: @mark seriously though, this is not trivial to do in pure JavaScript. You will want to rely on *some* framework that has worked out the numerous possible issues with finding child elements, fading, etc.

Comment: Is there a reason WHY you would want to use pure Javascript?  One major reason jQuery and frameworks like it exist is simple cross-browser compatibility.  It's obviously possible since it is attainable with jQuery, but it's definitely not going to be easy.  I would expect that snippet to convert into at least 20 times the amount of code.

Comment: I suppose you could look at the jquery source to see how the methods you have used are implemented and go from there.

Comment: jQuery does the cross browser support for you. Please give a reason why you would like to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Pekka no. jQUery is different from a DOM shim. You want a library that implements DOM3 events.

Comment: @Raynos DOM3 events? I don't understand.

Comment: @Pekka there's a difference between using a library that abstracts out cross browser issues. One that defines `.addEventListener` and jQuery. `.addEventListener`. You just need a library that implements [DOM level 3 events w3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/)

Comment: @mark: please read the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978799/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-jquery-code-to-javascript) and ask a specific question if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well for one thing -- jQuery was made to be cross browser.

There is such thing as a pure js fadeout, but it's hideously complicated. (thanks @Pekka)

Also you would need some library do to the special selecting you want in the DOM.

Comment: `There is no such thing as a pure js fadeout without a long animation function.` of course there is. But it's hideously complicated

Comment: @Pekka yes, that is basically what the intended wording was. i will fix that

Comment: @Pekka I doubt it's that complicated.

Comment: @Raynos if you want cross-browser support down to older IEs, I'm fairly sure it *is* going to be rather complicated. There is a number of quirks that need working around for it to work smoothly. Look at jQuery's `animate()` for example https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L122

Comment: @Pekka Oh you need a shim for `.addEventListener` once you have that it's smooth sailing. Of course `.animate` in jQUery has feature bloat.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it easy and possible?

No. Not without any libraries.

if you use DOM & ES5 shims then you might be able to get to some neat small code.