# Show/hide multiple Divs with checkbox without using ID's only class names

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I needed assistance with having the “show/hide div” below show and hide when you click on either of the checkboxes in a section. I am planning on having multiple sections and the number is unknown, so it will not be possible to use ID's. So I was looking for a generic way if a checkbox in one region is clicked the “show/hide” only shows up in that region. I know you can probably achieve this by writing individual code and assigning ID’s for each section, but is there a way to make it function like I am visioning to avoid having to constantly update of the code? Is it possible to just target the closest div or next to element to achieve this when the checkbox is checked/unchecked or call css classes?

Here is my HTML

```
<!--section 1 --> 
section 1
<div class="showHideDiv">SHOW/HIDE THIS DIV</div>
<div class="custom-input">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input class="" id="" name="" type="checkbox"><label class="" for="">E-mail</label>
        <input class="" id="" name="" type="checkbox"><label class="" for="">Print</label>
    </div>
</div>

section 2    
<!--section 2 -->
<div class="ShowHideDiv">SHOW/HIDE THIS DIV</div>
<div class="custom-input">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input class="" id="" name="" type="checkbox"><label class="" for="">E-mail</label>
        <input class="" id="" name="" type="checkbox"><label class="" for="">Print</label>
    </div>
</div>

section 3  
<!--section 3 -->
<div class="ShowHideDiv">SHOW/HIDE THIS DIV</div>
<div class="custom-input">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input class="" id="" name="" type="checkbox"><label class="" for="">E-mail</label>
        <input class="" id="" name="" type="checkbox"><label class="" for="">Print</label>
    </div>
</div>

section 4    
<!--section 4 -->
<div class="ShowHideDiv">SHOW/HIDE THIS DIV</div>
<div class="custom-input">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input class="" id="" name="" type="checkbox"><label class="" for="">E-mail</label>
        <input class="" id="" name="" type="checkbox"><label class="" for="">Print</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please format properly your code? indentation and so on?

Comment: sorry its should be better now

Comment: No, it's not better as you can see.

Comment: If you only indented your code you would see **what a mess it actually is**. http://jsbin.com/naniva/2/edit <-- here (thanks to proper formatting) you can see that you're missing a bunch of `</div>` tags

Comment: and until your HTML is not well formatted you don't have much to play with JS

Comment: What you talking about ? the code is formatted properly. Can you please help you are confusing me...

Comment: Sure, now it's formattted after Stephen formatted it: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25070945/revisions, and me in this demo: http://jsbin.com/naniva/2/edit. I've also warned you that you have unclosed (`</div>`) tags. Have you fixed those errors?

Comment: If you still don't understand, where are you closing your `<div class="custom-input">` tags?

Comment: Ok I closed them sorry. Custom-input just wraps around the checkboxes in each section.

Comment: Wow nice you did again a total mess! :) The HTML code you see above it's exactly called *Malformatted, Unindented HTML* and makes anyone who tries to help you the job quite difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you fix the invalid html (you need to add a closing `</div>` for `<div class="custom-input">`), you could use

```
$(this).closest('.custom-input').prev('.ShowHideDiv') //where $(this) is the checkbox
```

[Refer this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45NRN/) for an example (based on the comments) that hides the `<div>` if none of the checkboxes are checked, and displays the `<div>` if one or both the checkboxes are checked

Comment: Hi Stephan, Thank you but this is not working even when I fixed the div error. My apologies on that. Is there a script that will work and show and hide the div?

Comment: Just add `.toggle()` if you want to change the visibility state (It wasn't clear what you wanted to do - I just showed you how to select it)

Comment: thanks Stephan.. is there any way this can work with jquery. 1.6? I know its old but seems like that version it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to post your complete jquery code so I can check, but if your using `$('.checkbox').on('click', function() {...` the you need to replace `.on` with `.live` for earlier versions of jquery.

Comment: one problem I have is that you used click as a method. So if one checkbox clicks it and the other does its causing issues.. is there anyway to have the div hidden and then if a box is checked it appears. and if you check the other box it doesn't hide it

Comment: Yes of course, but the reason I did not show the full code is because it was not clear what you want to happen. What visibility state do you want when: (a) both are unchecked; (b) only the first one is checked; (c) only the second one is checked; (d) both are checked?

Comment: a) show no div b) show div c) show div ... when one is checked and checking the other should not close it. they both have to be unchecked

Comment: thank you so much. It works great.. one last question. Is it possible to achieve this with just regaular javascript without calling the jquery?

Comment: Yes, but have a go yourself, and if you have problems, ask a new question - after all you tagged this one `jquery` :)

Comment: please can you help? I am really not skilled enough to write it. I am not proficient at all in javascript

Comment: You need to understand how SO works. I have answered the question you posted. If it solved your problem, then up vote and/or accept.  What your asking now is a different question so should be posted as a **new** question to help others as well, but you should at least make an attempt or you will get down votes. Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) to get you started. Also have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978799/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-jquery-code-to-javascript), in particular comments about "why do this"

Comment: hi so what if the <div class="showHideDiv">SHOW/HIDE THIS DIV</div> was wrapped in a div? how would that work?

Comment: @dalondon I am not sure why you tried to deface my answer. It shows very poor manners... do you mind sharing why you thought it was appropriate to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$('.checkbox').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.custom-input').prev('.showHideDiv').toggle();
});
```

Just make sure your markup is closed properly and all your `showHideDiv` classes are **exactly** the same (i.e. right now some start with lowercase and some start with uppercase)

**updated**

http://jsfiddle.net/EEj29/