# jquery to Plain Javascript conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to convert a line of jQuery code to plain old JavaScript. Can someone guide me?

```
$('a').filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).text() === "Officer Title Equivalent*";
}).each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("*", "<span style='color:red'>*</span>"));
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978799/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-jquery-code-to-javascript

Comment: What kind of support is needed (particularly IE)? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: See http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ or https://plainjs.com/javascript/

Comment: @JosephMarikle Mostly IE > 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a literal translation...

Grab the `a` elements.

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Use `slice` to coerce the nodelist into an array of nodes, then use the array methods `filter` and `forEach`

```
[].slice.call(a).filter(function (el) {
  return el.textContent === 'Officer Title Equivalent*';
}).forEach(function (el) {
  el.innerHTML = el.textContent.replace('*', '<span style="color:red">*</span>');
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/1xe8d3vn/2/)

The other option is what gurvinder hinted at in his question - no need for `filter`, just a conditional:

```
[].slice.call(a).forEach(function (el) {
  var txt = el.textContent;
  if (txt === 'Officer Title Equivalent*') {
    el.innerHTML = txt.replace('*', '<span style="color:red">*</span>');
  }
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/xjsq0yen/1/)

And Joseph (comments) is right - you can also do:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function (el) {
  var txt = el.textContent;
  if (txt === 'Officer Title Equivalent*') {
    el.innerHTML = txt.replace('*', '<span style="color:red">*</span>');
  }
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/28sp6mzv/4/)

Comment: Nice answer.  Is there a particular reason you chose to use `[].slice.call(a).forEach(function (el) { ...` instead of `Array.prototype.filter.call(a, function (el) { ...`?  Is there a significant compatibility difference?

Comment: Now that I look at it closer, you could even use `[].filter.call(a, function (el) { ...` in a similar vein to what you have already.

Comment: @JosephMarikle, habit, mostly.

Answer (score 0):

it should be as simple as

```
var allAnchors = document.getElementsByTagName( "a" );
for ( var counter = 0; counter < allAnchors.length; counter++)
{
   var node = allAnchors.item( counter );
   if ( node.innerText === "Officer Title Equivalent*" )
   {
      node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace("*", "<span style='color:red'>*</span>");
   }
}
```

should work on [most browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: You can't use `forEach` on something that's not an array - something you would have figured out if you'd tested your code before posting it.

Comment: @Andy what about now?

Comment: Why don't _you_ test it?