# jQuery to VannilaJS (export function using ES6)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script transforms the first letter of each word into capital letters, except for some words that are part of the arrays in the variables `wordContainAt`, `wordsToIgnore`, `wordUpperCase`.

I'm having trouble refactoring the code made in `jQuery` to`Vannila JS`, using the `ES6 export`.

I think I didn't understand this concept very well, besides not being able to get the `this` object, within the scope of the function.

Can someone help me ?

**jQuery**

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $.fn.capitalize = function() {
        // words to ignore
        let wordContainAt = '@',
            wordsToIgnore = ['to', 'and', 'the', 'it', 'or', 'that', 'this'],
            wordUpperCase = ['S.A', 'SMS', 'USA'],
            minLength = 2;

        function getWords(str) {
            if (str == undefined) {
                str = 'abc def';
            } else {
                str = str;
            }
            return str.match(/\S+\s*/g);
        }
        this.each(function() {
            let words = getWords(this.value);
            console.log(words);
            $.each(words, function(i, word) {
                // only continues if the word is not in the ignore list or contains at '@'
                if (word.indexOf(wordContainAt) != -1) {
                    words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
                } else if (wordUpperCase.indexOf($.trim(word).toUpperCase()) != -1) {
                    words[i] = words[i].toUpperCase();
                } else if (wordsToIgnore.indexOf($.trim(word)) == -1 && $.trim(word).length > minLength) {
                    words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
                } else {
                    words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
                }
            });
            if (this.value != '') {
                this.value = words.join('');
            }
        });
    };

    // field onblur with class .lower
    $(document).on('blur', '.lower', function() {
        $(this).capitalize();
    }).capitalize();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="lower" />
```

**Vannila JS Syntax example**

```
const capitalizeTheWord = () => {

    console.log('hello World');
    const inputWordCapitalize = document.querySelector('input.lower');
    inputWordCapitalize.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
        //
    });
};

export default capitalizeTheWord();
```

Comment: Converting jQuery to vanilla JS is independent of exporting. Work on one thing at a time.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978799/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-jquery-code-to-javascript for resources on converting JQ to JS.